# MT4 Manager API => .Net ClrWrapper

Tags: c#, .net, mql4, metatrader4, mt4

I am using mtmanapi.dll with a .Net CLR wrapper

I am getting correct `Ask` and `Bid` values for symbols without any special characters in the `Symbol` name - ( e.g. `EURUSD`, `GBPUSD` and so on ), but if symbols have some special character in it ( e.g. `EURUSD'`, `GBPUSD0` and so on ), then it's not fetching `Ask` and `Bid` value using a `SymbolInfoGet()` method.

Comment: Are you using third party plugin? Can you please share the code to access mt4 manager API?

Answer (score 1):

It should work and below code returns quotes for US100, OIL.WTI, 225JPY from my server. I am using `SymbolInfoUpdated()` however it's similar to `SymbolInfoGet()`. But there are few notes:

1) you might need to call `mt.SymbolsRefresh();` and `mt.SymbolAdd(symbol.Name);` before switching to pumping

2) `SymbolInfoGet()` will return you last received quote in pumping. So if you connect on Saturday and call it, it won't return anything until Monday

```
using (var mt = new ClrWrapper(new ConnectionParameters {Login = 0, Password = "", Server = "" }))
{
    var symbols = mt.CfgRequestSymbol();
    mt.SymbolsRefresh();
    foreach (var symbol in symbols)
    {
        mt.SymbolAdd(symbol.Name);
    }
    mt.PumpingSwitchEx(PumpingMode.Default);

    mt.BidAskUpdated += (sender, args) =>
    {
        var total = 0;
        do
        {
            var symbolsInfos = mt.SymbolInfoUpdated();
            foreach (var symbolInfo in symbolsInfos)
            {                            
                if (!symbolInfo.Symbol.All(char.IsLetter))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", DateTime.Now, symbolInfo.Symbol, symbolInfo.Bid);
                }
            }
            total = symbolsInfos.Count;
        } while (total > 0);
    };

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the wrapper code used to connect with mtmanapi.dll ? It would be of great hep.

Comment: I can share the code written so far, can you please share ur email? It would be great if you can help me.

Comment: I have written wrapper code but it does not seem to work. I am unable to identify the issue. Hence need your help.

Comment: Thanks a lot. email : rahul.007j@gmail.com

Comment: Also is it possible to share the code you have uploaded on github (since it has been removed I cannot find it anywhere)?

Comment: Thank you very much. It was not so obvious = )